# PHP: wkhtmltopdf snappy (wrapper) fails

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

i have a problem using wkhtmltopdf with snappy.
I has installed wkhtmltopdf with homebrew on mac osx.

I use this code to display PDF in Browser:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
    require_once('snappy/autoload.php');    
    use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
    $snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');    
    echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');   
?>
```

Instead of displaying the PDF in the browser, the script opens the terminal. After i click on the terminal it starts downloading the `file.pdf`. The `file.pdf` shows the correct github page.

What i am doing wrong? 
And whats the best solution to manage wkhtmltopdf's binary path that the script is working on several systems (debian, windows, ..).

**EDIT:**

Oh sorry.. i changed `attachment` to `inline` and the browser displays the PDF.
But i must click on the terminal first..